# Build an Ionic application for ubuntu phone as click package

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch, application-development, click-packages

Hello fellows I have the following application:
https://github.com/kawai-developers/faster

And I try to build it as a scope for ubuntu phone

I managed to add the platfrom for ubuntu with the followign command:

```
ionic platform add ubuntu
```

And that generated to me the following files on `./platforms/ubuntu`:

[image]

Where on folder `www` is any source code with the angular libraries inside-

But how all these files above I will build it as a click package?

When I run on the terminal:

```
ionic ubuntu build
```

I get on `./platforms/ubuntu/native` the following files:

And the following response:

```
Running command: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Javascript/Ionic/Faster/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Javascript/Ionic/Faster
add to body class: platform-ubuntu
Running command: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Javascript/Ionic/Faster/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build 
Building...
Note: to build a debian package, run: 
 cd /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/Javascript/Ionic/Faster/platforms/ubuntu/native/com.ionicframework.faster723190; debuild
```

And I have the option to build a .deb package. But not as a .click one;

I tried the following commands:

```
cd  ./platforms/ubuntu
click build .
click verify com.ionicframework.faster723190_0.0.1_all.click
```

The last command gave me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/verify.py", line 37, in run
    installer.audit(package_path, slow=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/install.py", line 190, in audit
    'No "framework" entry in manifest')
```

Also Ubuntu SDK does not help to import existing ionic projects that have not inserted before.

Note: Before I execute any sort of command I moves to my project's folder by typing:

```
cd <project folder>
```